# Name series with dash

Tags: influxdb

I have a series with a name contain dash (exemple: foo-bar), i can't apply queries for this series. I got the message error : ERROR: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting $end select * from foo-bar ^

Comment: I've no idea even what influxdb is, but I expect you need to add quotes around `foo-bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full syntax for queries is here on the InfluxDB website. Any identifiers containing characters other than A-z,0-9,_ must be quoted. https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/query_language/query_syntax.html